# Show a Hidden Field When One Menu Item is Clicked - Advanced Custom Fields Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have a disclaimer div that I want to show when a certain menu item is clicked. I have my Jquery correctly showing my hidden divs with this script: 
    `$(function(){
    var $allItems =  $(".food-container > div");
    $(document.body).on("click", "a.menu-item", function () {
    var id = this.id, itemId = ".food-container > #item-" + id;
    $allItems.not($(itemId).fadeToggle()).hide();
    });
    });`
I am using Advanced Custom Fields Repeater Field, so I need to hide the field out of the Repeater loop. The menu id that I have is "4". So I just need to connect the disclaimer div which is "burger-disclaimer" to the #4 click event.

Here is the menu: https://jsfiddle.net/42gqu9r9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should put you on the right path. I am grabbing the ID of the click event (evt variable), to see what was selected.

HTML:

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-item">Appetizers<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
<a id="2" href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-item">Tex-Mex<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
<a id="3" href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-item">Salads<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
<a id="4" href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-item">Burgers<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
<div class="food-container">
    <div id="item-1" style="display: none;">
        <div class="food">
            <h3>Mac N Cheese Bites</h3> Breaded, then fried macaroni, stuffed with cheese</div>
        <div class="price"> $8 </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-2" style="display: none;">
        <div class="food">
            <h3>Salads</h3> Salads
        </div>
        <div class="price"> $8 </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-3" style="display: none;">
        <div class="food">
            <h3>Tex-Mex</h3> Tex-Mex
        </div>
        <div class="price"> $8 </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-4" style="display: none;">
        <div class="food">
            <h3>Burgers</h3> Burger
        </div>
        <div class="price"> $8 </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="burger-disclaimer">
    *All sandwiches and burgers are served with fries or potato chips. Side salad and onion rings available as side, add $2 upcharge
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var $allItems = $(".food-container > div");
    $(document.body).on("click", "a.menu-item", function(evt) {
        var id = this.id,
            itemId = ".food-container > #item-" + id;
        $allItems.not($(itemId).fadeToggle()).hide();
        if (evt.target.id == 4) {
            $('.burger-disclaimer').toggle();
        } else {
            $('.burger-disclaimer').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And your updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6y0ymao8/

Comment: This was a quick update, to make it all match swith the `.toggle();` to `.fadeToggle();` Also you can just put the `<div>` for the disclaimer up in the `<div id='item-4`>`. I am not familiar with the advanced-custom-fields so this may have not been an option.